# Why doesn't my code uses default non parameterized constructor, if one constructor with parameters is defined?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

Okay so, I've my main class which loads everything in from my framework. What I'm having trouble with now is my collision detection; I've got it so if it hits something, something will happen. I've a method that calls a GameOverUI in the GameScreen class, but I want to use that in my Enemy.class .. I've created a new instance for the object but it's saying its undefined. What I dont get is the class has no definition but a method called GameScreen is defined by (Game game).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import com.vaughanslater.framework.Game;
import com.vaughanslater.framework.Graphics;
import com.vaughanslater.framework.Image;
import com.vaughanslater.framework.Input.TouchEvent;
import com.vaughanslater.framework.Screen;

public class GameScreen extends Screen {
    enum GameState { 
        Ready, Running, Paused, GameOver
    }

    GameState state = GameState.Ready;

    // Variable Setup

    private static Background bg1, bg2;
    private static Robot robot;
    public static Heliboy hb, hb2;

    private Image currentSprite, character, character2, character3, heliboy,
            heliboy2, heliboy3, heliboy4, heliboy5;
    private Animation anim, hanim;

    private ArrayList tilearray = new ArrayList();

    int livesLeft = 1;
    Paint paint, paint2;

    public GameScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);

        // Initialize game objects here

        bg1 = new Background(0, 0);
        bg2 = new Background(2160, 0);
        robot = new Robot();
        hb = new Heliboy(340, 360);
        hb2 = new Heliboy(700, 360);

        character = Assets.character;
        character2 = Assets.character2;
        character3 = Assets.character3;

        heliboy = Assets.heliboy;
        heliboy2 = Assets.heliboy2;
        heliboy3 = Assets.heliboy3;
        heliboy4 = Assets.heliboy4;
        heliboy5 = Assets.heliboy5;

        anim = new Animation();
        anim.addFrame(character, 1250);
        anim.addFrame(character2, 50);
        anim.addFrame(character3, 50);
        anim.addFrame(character2, 50);

        hanim = new Animation();
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy2, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy3, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy4, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy5, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy4, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy3, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy2, 100);

        currentSprite = anim.getImage();

        loadMap();

        // Defining a paint object
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(30);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setTextSize(100);
        paint2.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    }

    private void loadMap() {
        ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(SampleGame.map);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            // no more lines to read
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }

            if (!line.startsWith("!")) {
                lines.add(line);
                width = Math.max(width, line.length());

            }
        }
        height = lines.size();

        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            String line = (String) lines.get(j);
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

                if (i < line.length()) {
                    char ch = line.charAt(i);
                    Tile t = new Tile(i, j, Character.getNumericValue(ch));
                    tilearray.add(t);
                }

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {

        List touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();

        // We have four separate update methods in this example.
        // Depending on the state of the game, we call different update methods.
        // Refer to Unit 3's code. We did a similar thing without separating the
        // update methods.

        if (state == GameState.Ready)
            updateReady(touchEvents);
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            updateRunning(touchEvents, deltaTime);
        if (state == GameState.Paused)
            updatePaused(touchEvents);
        if (state == GameState.GameOver)
            updateGameOver(touchEvents);
    }

    private void updateReady(List touchEvents) {

        // This example starts with a "Ready" screen.
        // When the user touches the screen, the game begins.
        // state now becomes GameState.Running.
        // Now the updateRunning() method will be called!

        if (touchEvents.size() > 0)
            state = GameState.Running;
    }

    private void updateRunning(List touchEvents, float deltaTime) {

        // This is identical to the update() method from our Unit 2/3 game.

        // 1. All touch input is handled here:
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = (TouchEvent) touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {

                if (event.x > 400) {
                    robot.jump();
                    currentSprite = anim.getImage();
                    robot.setDucked(false);
                }

                else if (inBounds(event, 0, 350, 65, 65)) {

                    if (robot.isDucked() == false && robot.isJumped() == false
                            && robot.isReadyToFire()) {
                        robot.shoot();
                    }
                }

                else if (event.x < 400
                        && robot.isJumped() == false) {
                    currentSprite = Assets.characterDown;
                    robot.setDucked(true);
                    robot.setSpeedX(0);

                }

                //if (event.x > 400) {
                // Move right.
                //  robot.moveRight();
                //  robot.setMovingRight(true);
                //}

            }

            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

                if (event.x < 400) {
                    currentSprite = anim.getImage();
                    robot.setDucked(false);

                }

                if (inBounds(event, 0, 0, 35, 35)) {
                    pause();

                }

                if (event.x > 400) {
                    // Move right.
                    robot.stopRight();
                }
            }

        }

        // 2. Check miscellaneous events like death:

        if (livesLeft == 0) {
            state = GameState.GameOver;
        }

        // 3. Call individual update() methods here.
        // This is where all the game updates happen.
        // For example, robot.update();
        robot.update();
        if (robot.isJumped()) {
            currentSprite = Assets.characterJump;
        } else if (robot.isJumped() == false && robot.isDucked() == false) {
            currentSprite = anim.getImage();
        }

        ArrayList projectiles = robot.getProjectiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++) {
            Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
            if (p.isVisible() == true) {
                p.update();
            } else {
                projectiles.remove(i);
            }
        }

        updateTiles();
        hb.update();
        hb2.update();
        bg1.update();
        bg2.update();
        animate();

        if (robot.getCenterY() > 500) {
            state = GameState.GameOver;
        }
    }

    private boolean inBounds(TouchEvent event, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {
        if (event.x > x && event.x < x + width - 1 && event.y > y
                && event.y < y + height - 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void updatePaused(List touchEvents) {
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = (TouchEvent) touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
                if (inBounds(event, 0, 0, 800, 240)) {

                    if (!inBounds(event, 0, 0, 35, 35)) {
                        resume();
                    }
                }

                if (inBounds(event, 0, 240, 800, 240)) {
                    nullify();
                    goToMenu();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateGameOver(List touchEvents) {
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = (TouchEvent) touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {
                if (inBounds(event, 0, 0, 800, 480)) {
                    nullify();
                    game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void updateTiles() {

        for (int i = 0; i < tilearray.size(); i++) {
            Tile t = (Tile) tilearray.get(i);
            t.update();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(float deltaTime) {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        g.drawImage(Assets.background, bg1.getBgX(), bg1.getBgY());
        g.drawImage(Assets.background, bg2.getBgX(), bg2.getBgY());
        paintTiles(g);

        ArrayList projectiles = robot.getProjectiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++) {
            Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
            g.drawRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 5, Color.YELLOW);
        }
        // First draw the game elements.

        g.drawImage(currentSprite, robot.getCenterX() - -15,
                robot.getCenterY() - -17);
        g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb.getCenterX() - 48,
                hb.getCenterY() - 48);
        g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb2.getCenterX() - 48,
                hb2.getCenterY() - 48);

        // Example:
        // g.drawImage(Assets.background, 0, 0);
        // g.drawImage(Assets.character, characterX, characterY);

        // Secondly, draw the UI above the game elements.
        if (state == GameState.Ready)
            drawReadyUI();
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            drawRunningUI();
        if (state == GameState.Paused)
            drawPausedUI();
        if (state == GameState.GameOver)
            drawGameOverUI();

    }

    private void paintTiles(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tilearray.size(); i++) {
            Tile t = (Tile) tilearray.get(i);
            if (t.type != 0) {
                g.drawImage(t.getTileImage(), t.getTileX(), t.getTileY());
            }
        }
    }

    public void animate() {
        anim.update(10);
        hanim.update(50);
    }

    private void nullify() {

        // Set all variables to null. You will be recreating them in the
        // constructor.
        paint = null;
        bg1 = null;
        bg2 = null;
        robot = null;
        hb = null;
        hb2 = null;
        currentSprite = null;
        character = null;
        character2 = null;
        character3 = null;
        heliboy = null;
        heliboy2 = null;
        heliboy3 = null;
        heliboy4 = null;
        heliboy5 = null;
        anim = null;
        hanim = null;

        // Call garbage collector to clean up memory.
        System.gc();

    }

    private void drawReadyUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        g.drawARGB(155, 0, 0, 0);
        g.drawString("Tap to Start.", 400, 240, paint);

    }

    private void drawRunningUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        //g.drawImage(Assets.button, 0, 285, 0, 0, 65, 65);
        //g.drawImage(Assets.button, 0, 350, 0, 65, 65, 65);
        //g.drawImage(Assets.button, 0, 415, 0, 130, 65, 65);
        g.drawImage(Assets.button, 0, 0, 0, 195, 35, 35);

    }

    private void drawPausedUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        // Darken the entire screen so you can display the Paused screen.
        g.drawARGB(155, 0, 0, 0);
        g.drawString("Resume", 400, 165, paint2);
        g.drawString("Menu", 400, 360, paint2);

    }

    public void drawGameOverUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 1281, 801, Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("GAME OVER.", 400, 240, paint2);
        g.drawString("Tap to return.", 400, 290, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            state = GameState.Paused;

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        if (state == GameState.Paused)
            state = GameState.Running;
    }

    public GameState getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(GameState state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void backButton() {
        pause();
    }

    private void goToMenu() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));

    }

    public static Background getBg1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return bg1;
    }

    public static Background getBg2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return bg2;
    }

    public static Robot getRobot() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return robot;
    }


}
```

Heres my enemy class too:

```
import android.graphics.Rect;

public class Enemy {

    private int power, centerX, speedX, centerY;
    private Background bg = GameScreen.getBg1();
    private Robot robot = GameScreen.getRobot();
    public Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    public int health = 5;
    private int movementSpeed;

    // Behavioural Methods
    public void update() {
        follow();
        centerX += speedX;
        speedX = bg.getSpeedX() * 5 + movementSpeed;
        r.set(centerX - 25, centerY - 25, centerX + 25, centerY + 35);

        if (Rect.intersects(r, Robot.yellowRed)) {
            checkCollision();
        }

    }
private void checkCollision() {
    if (Rect.intersects(r, Robot.rect) || Rect.intersects(r, Robot.rect2)
            || Rect.intersects(r, Robot.rect3)
            || Rect.intersects(r, Robot.rect4)) {
        GameScreen state = new GameScreen(); // This is where it errors
    }
}

public void follow() {

    if (centerX < -95 || centerX > 810) {
        movementSpeed = 0;
    }

    else if (Math.abs(robot.getCenterX() - centerX) < 5) {
        movementSpeed = 0;
    }

    else {

        if (robot.getCenterX() >= centerX) {
            movementSpeed = 1;
        } else {
            movementSpeed = -1;
        }
    }

}

public void die() {

}

public void attack() {

}

public int getPower() {
    return power;
}

public int getSpeedX() {
    return speedX;
}

public int getCenterX() {
    return centerX;
}

public int getCenterY() {
    return centerY;
}

public Background getBg() {
    return bg;
}

public void setPower(int power) {
    this.power = power;
}

public void setSpeedX(int speedX) {
    this.speedX = speedX;
}

public void setCenterX(int centerX) {
    this.centerX = centerX;
}

public void setCenterY(int centerY) {
    this.centerY = centerY;
}

public void setBg(Background bg) {
    this.bg = bg;
}
```

}

So here is where it errors:

```
GameScreen state = new GameScreen(); // This is where it errors
```

I dont get it, I'm not calling the method GameScreen(Game game) which is defined, but I'm calling the class which isn't. I want to use the drawGameOverUI();.

Sorry for the wall of code.. atleast you can see everthing.

Comment: You don't have a no-args constructor in your `GameScreen` class.

Comment: Calling the defined constructor seems like a better choice than the undefined.

Comment: that's a lot of code...

Comment: Please give a short example that is enough for your question.

Answer (score 5):

If you define any constructor , default constructor is never used. Please define implementation of GameScreen() or remove the implementation of GameScreen(Game game).

Define a default constructor like this -

```
  public GameScreen() {
        super();

        // Initialize game objects here

        bg1 = new Background(0, 0);
        bg2 = new Background(2160, 0);
        robot = new Robot();
        hb = new Heliboy(340, 360);
        hb2 = new Heliboy(700, 360);

        character = Assets.character;
        character2 = Assets.character2;
        character3 = Assets.character3;

        heliboy = Assets.heliboy;
        heliboy2 = Assets.heliboy2;
        heliboy3 = Assets.heliboy3;
        heliboy4 = Assets.heliboy4;
        heliboy5 = Assets.heliboy5;

        anim = new Animation();
        anim.addFrame(character, 1250);
        anim.addFrame(character2, 50);
        anim.addFrame(character3, 50);
        anim.addFrame(character2, 50);

        hanim = new Animation();
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy2, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy3, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy4, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy5, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy4, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy3, 100);
        hanim.addFrame(heliboy2, 100);

        currentSprite = anim.getImage();

        loadMap();

        // Defining a paint object
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(30);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setTextSize(100);
        paint2.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    }
```

Comment: The issue is GameScreen needs (Game game) to be called through other methods. So I cant remove the implementation. Which leaves me to think I HAVE to define implementation of GameScreen() .. of which I'm not sure..

Comment: @user3245541 If a `GameScreen` object **needs** a `Game`, then what do you want the effect of `new GameScreen()` to be if you **don't** give it a `Game`?

Comment: just provide a non paramterized constructor with all instance variables initialized to their default values. That will be all safe to do as this is what your default constructor was expected to do.

Comment: Sorry, but how would I do that? Sorry I'm a moron and I'm still learning OOP. Again, I want to use the method drawGameOverUI() from Gamescreen.class & use it in Enemy.class. Is basically what I'm trying to do.

Comment: i have added the default constructor implementation. Please try this.

Comment: It really seems to dislike that, what I'm getting confused is; I'm not trying to load the method GameScreen, I'm trying to load the method drawGameOverUI from the CLASS GameScreen. I'm not sure why its trying to load that method. It errors on super(); saying "Screen is undefined".

Answer (score 2):

By defining a constructor that accepts an argument you are forcing users to call it.

If you want one without a mandatory game param, define one.